# recvfrom(2) receives UDP broadcast twice, but tcpdump(8) receives it only once

Tags: linux, sockets, interface, udp, broadcast

**Summary**: I want to receive packets from a single interface, but `setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iface, 1 + strlen(iface))` doesn't play well with `recvfrom` and shows all packets on all interfaces. `tcpdump` works well, however.

I have a strong feeling that there's something wrong with the receiver program, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

---

I'm working with a Netronome Agilio CX SmartNIC. The two ports on the NIC are connected together with one cable, and the port on the motherboard are connected to the wall (so I can SSH into it). The board-loaded NIC is `eth0` in the OS, while the SmartNIC presents two interfaces as `enp1s0np0` and `enp1s0np1`.

Because the two interfaces on the SmartNIC has no associated IP addresses, I have to send broadcast to one port so it arrives at the other port. For now, I send to `enp1s0np0` and expect it from `enp1s0np1`.

I have also deployed a XDP offload program that modifies part of the packet so I can know whether the packet arrives at `enp1s0np1`. The program changes the string at position 28~35 to another string (of the form `!......!`).

The problem I am having is, I wrote a receiver program myself, and it receives **two** packets for every packet I send - the first is the original, while the second is the XDP-modified packet. However, `tcpdump` only receives the modified packet (expected behavior).

I am unsure why my program is getting it twice - I don't think it should be able to see the unmodified packet.

This is the packet sender program. It reads 32 double-precision floating point numbers and packs them into a 256-byte block, and prepends the block with 16 bytes of "magic numbers".

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include "config.h"
#include "util.h"

typedef unsigned char byte;

void sanity_check(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sanity_check();

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
        errorexit("socket");

    char iface[16] = "enp1s0np0";
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iface, 1 + strlen(iface)))
        errorexit("setsockopt");
    int optval = -1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST | SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(int)))
        errorexit("setsockopt");

    struct sockaddr_in target_addr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_addr.s_addr = 0xFFFFFFFF,
        .sin_port = htons(6666)
    };

    byte buf[272];
    // Prepare data
    {
        unsigned long magic = MAGIC;
        memcpy(buf + 0, &magic, sizeof magic);
        unsigned long zero = 0UL;
        memcpy(buf + 8, &zero, sizeof zero);
        double data;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            scanf(" %lf", &data);
            memcpy(buf + 16 + 8 * i, &data, sizeof data);
        }
    }

    int sent = sendto(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&target_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if (sent != 0)
        errorexit("send");
    printf("%d bytes sent.\n", sent);

    // if (shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR))
    if (close(sock))
        errorexit("close");

    return 0;
}

void sanity_check(void) {
    if (getuid() || geteuid()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Need root to proceed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

This is the receiver program. In fact, it's receiving *every single* packet that comes into the machine, with most of them being SSH data. I had to add checks for  the magic number or it just spams the terminal. I guess it just failed to listen to the specific interface. (Check is `if (buf[28] != '!' || buf[35] != '!') continue;`)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include "config.h"
#include "util.h"

typedef unsigned char byte;

void sanity_check(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sanity_check();

    int sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(3));
    if (sock < 0)
        errorexit("socket");

    char iface[16] = "enp1s0np1";
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iface, 1 + strlen(iface)))
        errorexit("setsockopt");

    struct sockaddr_in target_addr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY),
        .sin_port = htons(UDP_PORT)
    };

    size_t bufsize = 8192;
    byte *buf = malloc(bufsize);
    unsigned long magic = MAGIC;
    int saddr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    printf("Preparing to receive... ");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (1) {
        int received = recvfrom(sock, buf, bufsize, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&target_addr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
        if (received < 0)
            errorexit("receive");
        if (received == 0)
            break;
        else if (buf[28] != '!' || buf[35] != '!') // Magic check
            continue;
        printf("%d bytes received.\n", received);
        hexdump(buf, received);
    }

    if (close(sock))
        errorexit("close");

    free(buf);
    return 0;
}

void sanity_check(void) {
    if (getuid() || geteuid()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Need root to proceed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The file `util.c` ([link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/iBug/2fb012978dc71d58ab9ad8f1417c1f3a)) contains two utility functions (`errorexit` which is just a wrapper of `perror` and `exit`, and a badly hand-crafted `hexdump` function for displaying) and is irrelevant here.

The constant `MAGIC` is defined as

```c
#define MAGIC 0x216C7174786A7A21UL // string "!zjxtql!"
```

Here's the console output of my program (`recv.c` compiled into `recv`) and the tcpdump command, with irrelevant data truncated. Before both programs are killed, only one packet is sent from the sender program. The special thing to note is the data at position 28 (was originally `!zjxtql!`, should be modified to `!wjfskb!` by the XDP offload program).

```
$ sudo ./recv
Preparing to receive...
300 bytes received.
00000000  45 00 01 2C 4C 1A 40 00  40 11 B4 7F 72 D6 C6 51  |E..,L.@.@...r..Q|
00000010  FF FF FF FF B0 9F 1A 0A  01 18 3A 51 21 7A 6A 78  |..........:Q!zjx|
00000020  74 71 6C 21 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 29 5C 8F C2  |tql!........)\..|
00000120  14 AE F7 3F AE 47 E1 7A  14 AE F7 3F              |...?.G.z...?|
0000012C
300 bytes received.
00000000  45 00 01 2C 4C 1A 40 00  40 11 B4 7F 72 D6 C6 51  |E..,L.@.@...r..Q|
00000010  FF FF FF FF B0 9F 1A 0A  01 18 C0 9B 21 77 6A 66  |............!wjf|
00000020  73 6B 62 21 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 29 5C 8F C2  |skb!........)\..|
00000120  14 AE F7 3F AE 47 E1 7A  14 AE F7 3F              |...?.G.z...?|
0000012C
^C
$ sudo tcpdump -vv -X -i enp1s0np1 port 6666
tcpdump: listening on enp1s0np1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
04:53:52.819657 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8595, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 300)
    agilio1415.47585 > 255.255.255.255.ircu-2: [bad udp cksum 0xb759 -> 0xc274!] UDP, length 272
        0x0000:  4500 012c 2193 4000 4011 df06 72d6 c651  E..,!.@.@...r..Q
        0x0010:  ffff ffff b9e1 1a0a 0118 b759 2177 6a66  ...........Y!wjf
        0x0020:  736b 6221 0000 0000 0000 0000 295c 8fc2  skb!........)\..
        0x0120:  14ae f73f ae47 e17a 14ae f73f            ...?.G.z...?
^C
```

I have tried `strace`ing tcpdump and trying its job with `setsockopt`:

```sh
sudo strace -e setsockopt tcpdump -vv -X -i enp1s0np1 port 6666
```

which gives

```
setsockopt(3, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, {mr_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp1s0np1"), mr_type=PACKET_MR_PROMISC, mr_alen=0, mr_address=}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_AUXDATA, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_VERSION, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_RESERVE, [4], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_RX_RING, 0x7ffe9d8d1510, 28) = 0
setsockopt(7, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [8388608], 4) = 0
setsockopt(7, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [8388608], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, {len=1, filter=0x7fa5289de000}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, {len=24, filter=0x56025631f280}, 16) = 0
tcpdump: listening on enp1s0np1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

because I don't understand the others, I mimicked only the first call to `setsockopt` of tcpdump:

```c
struct packet_mreq mreq = {
    .mr_ifindex = if_nametoindex(iface),
    .mr_type = PACKET_MR_PROMISC,
    .mr_alen = 0
};
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)))
    errorexit("setsockopt");
```

The above code is a replacement for the `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE)` call in the receiver program, but I haven't observed any difference (still all packets from all interfaces are caught).

Comment: Unrelevant, but you can not set several socket options at one call. So this part of the source won't work: "SO_BROADCAST | SO_REUSEADDR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all that I'm missing is a `bind(2)`. Unfortunately, `SO_BINDTOINTERFACE` doesn't work with `AF_PACKET`, so `bind(2)` is the only solution.

The code isn't any complex:

```c
struct sockaddr_ll sll = {
    .sll_family = AF_PACKET,
    .sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(iface),
    .sll_protocol = htons(3) // 3 = ETH_P_ALL
};
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sll, sizeof sll))
    errorexit("sock");
```

From the same [`socket.7` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> `SO_BINDTOSOCKET`
>
> ... Note that this works only for some socket types, particularly `AF_INET` sockets.  **It is not supported for packet sockets** (use normal `bind(2)` there).

Hmmm, guess I should've read the manual more thoroughly.